# Convert a Hex number to a GUID with dashes

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have several hundred Hex numbers (32 char long) that were pulled from a sql db. I have them stored in an excel table and need to convert them to GUID with dashes. I have found an online converter, but it only does one at a time and this would be very time consuming (http://www.windowstricks.in/online-windows-guid-converter). Is there a way, either in Excel with VBA or Formulas or in SQL to convert these? It is not as simple as just adding the dashes into the correct places. I've tried that and it is not what I need to have happen. An example of the Hex and the converted dash separated GUID:

Hex

1. 6F414B9DFB178945A3641E40BC2A4AAB
2. C58C415E215CEC4D9B5100532573D3FA
3. 2B0BBF00A1403E41A333C805961CEA9F

GUID converted from the Hex above

1. 48a6c53b-941c-46e2-9964-680754f71666
2. ea0ba3f4-4905-4d9c-9d83-76c57bdb060a
3. 18cea3f7-e1d1-4609-a4bc-9bf6fec6a2d4

Any help you can give would be very appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/325648

Comment: I have seen that page @Stavr00, but that is not what I'm trying to do. In fact it's the Active Directory form that I've got and I'm trying to convert it to GUID so that I can use it in another program.

Comment: For the Hex value

`6F414B9DFB178945A3641E40BC2A4AAB`

it should be

`{9D4B416F-17FB-4589-A364-1E40BC2A4AAB}`

Comment: The online converter that I found gave me the values that I provided in the examples. Those three I've been able to run through my other program and pull in the correct information. I do not know how the online converter is doing this though. That is what i really need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function converts an hexadecimal String to a formatted GUID string:

```
Public Function ConvHexToGuid(hexa As String) As String
    Dim guid As String * 36
    Mid$(guid, 1) = Mid$(hexa, 7, 2)
    Mid$(guid, 3) = Mid$(hexa, 5, 2)
    Mid$(guid, 5) = Mid$(hexa, 3, 2)
    Mid$(guid, 7) = Mid$(hexa, 1, 2)
    Mid$(guid, 9) = "-"
    Mid$(guid, 10) = Mid$(hexa, 11, 2)
    Mid$(guid, 12) = Mid$(hexa, 9, 2)
    Mid$(guid, 14) = "-"
    Mid$(guid, 15) = Mid$(hexa, 15, 2)
    Mid$(guid, 17) = Mid$(hexa, 13, 2)
    Mid$(guid, 19) = "-"
    Mid$(guid, 20) = Mid$(hexa, 17, 4)
    Mid$(guid, 24) = "-"
    Mid$(guid, 25) = Mid$(hexa, 21, 16)
    ConvHexToGuid = guid
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The GUID to HEX is transposed as follows:

`0x00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF`

`{33221100-5544-7766-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}`

Comment: Thank you for that useful info! I never saw this anywhere in MS documentation or anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer. Thanks to @florent. I'm not sure why the GUID's came out differently and still worked the first time I was running this, but I have a solution. I did this using VBA code:

```
Sub CreateGUID()
    Dim count, GUIDConverted As String

    count = 2

    Do While Range("F" & count).Value <> ""
        Range("F" & count).Select
        GUIDConverted = Range("F" & count).Value
        GUIDConverted = ConvertHexToGUID(GUIDConverted)
        Range("H" & count).Value = GUIDConverted
        count = count + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Public Function ConvertHexToGUID(hexa As String) As String
    Dim guid As String * 36
    Mid$(guid, 1) = Mid$(hexa, 7, 2)
    Mid$(guid, 3) = Mid$(hexa, 5, 2)
    Mid$(guid, 5) = Mid$(hexa, 3, 2)
    Mid$(guid, 7) = Mid$(hexa, 1, 2)
    Mid$(guid, 9) = "-"
    Mid$(guid, 10) = Mid$(hexa, 11, 2)
    Mid$(guid, 12) = Mid$(hexa, 9, 2)
    Mid$(guid, 14) = "-"
    Mid$(guid, 15) = Mid$(hexa, 15, 2)
    Mid$(guid, 17) = Mid$(hexa, 13, 2)
    Mid$(guid, 19) = "-"
    Mid$(guid, 20) = Mid$(hexa, 17, 4)
    Mid$(guid, 24) = "-"
    Mid$(guid, 25) = Mid$(hexa, 21, 16)
    ConvertHexToGUID = guid
End Function
```

This worked for all of the Hex numbers that I had.
Thanks to all those who took time to make a response they did all help as I was working on this.